# Quick question for similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have that $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, we know that $B = P^{-1} A P$ for some invertible matrix $P$. 
Is it true that $A$ is also equal to $P^{-1}BP$? If not, how can we express $A$ in terms of $P^{-1}$, $P$ and $B$?

Comment: If $B = P^{-1} A P$, how would you go about solving for $A$?

Answer (score 1):

$B=P^{-1}AP$, Then $PBP^{-1}=PP^{-1}APP^{-1} =A$.